# App exits for unknown reason

Tags: android

I have a problem with my code:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.java.app.changeback">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp">


                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="150dp"
                        android:layout_height="250dp"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/who"
                        android:id="@+id/back_who"
                        android:layout_weight="1" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="150dp"
                        android:layout_height="250dp"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/grass"
                        android:id="@+id/back_grass"
                        android:layout_weight="1" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="150dp"
                        android:layout_height="250dp"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/home"
                        android:id="@+id/back_home"
                        android:layout_weight="1" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="150dp"
                        android:layout_height="250dp"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/green"
                        android:id="@+id/back_green"
                        android:layout_weight="1" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

        </HorizontalScrollView>

        <TextView
            android:text="Home"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="50dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="130dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:id="@+id/change_text" />

    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

I have checked the names of the images there are no errors. 
This is a picture of the photo folder

[my image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H2eyB.png)

When you run the program, it exits.

Comment: `... it exits` doesn't tell us much. Paste your logcat, to have a chance to get any help.

Comment: When I remove the image code the application works fine but when I let them do not open the page I am very confused

Comment: Can you elaborate on this? And post your logcat.

Comment: What are the sizes of the images? If they are multi-megabyte you will need to subsample them.